# What is the difference between a MonoDevelop solution file and a Visual Studio Solution file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, monodevelop

MonoDevelop allows you to save your solution in either MonoDevelop format or Visual Studio format. What is the difference between these two formats? Are they different ways or storing the same thing? If not, what does one store that the other does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a difference for the first version of MonoDevelop. They used their own *.mds file format. You can take a look for details on it in the MonoDevelop source code. But as far as i know, this file format (as well as .mdp, .mdw) is not intended to use with MonoDevelop 2+. The default solution format for the newest version of MonoDevelop is identical (as far as i know) to VisualStudio. Will appreciate if somebody will correct me if i am wrong =)

Comment: That makes sense--it would explain why Visual Studio format is the default in MonoDevelop 2+.

Answer (score 1):

monodevelop can open both monodevelop and visual studio .csproj files while visual studio can't open monodevelop format. monodevelop version (2.0+) by default saves the solution file in .csproj format.